# Talend tAggregateRow put same grouping into different rows

Tags: aggregate, talend

A screenshot of my output in tLogRow:

[image: a screenshot of my output in tlogrow]

tmap settings:

[image: tmap settings screenshot]

taggregaterow settings:

[image: taggreagterow settings screenshot]

the workflow:

[image: my ETL workflow]

What I want to do is grouping by "fckd_operator" and "fdtgl_pinjam", but as you can see, "wiros" and "08-2015" aren't being grouped correctly

Any ideas?

EDIT 11/29 -> adding workflow,tmap, and taggregate row screenshot

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your tAggregateRow settings so that we can see the settings. Without them it is hard to help.

Comment: added, sorry I forget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this only happens on my machine, but it is kinda stupid.

In my tmap settings, you can see that I use pattern "yyyy-MM" to format fdtgl_pinjam, but it seems that pattern in tmap date only affects the outputted text and not the value, hence make the grouping seems wrong.

My workaround is:

1. remove the pattern in tmap settings
2. using fdtgl_pinjam once more in tmap, but the value is Talend.getFirstDayOfMonth(fdtgl_pinjam), and group them using this field

It works now! :D

Comment: Good to know! Correct, patterns usually tends to puzzle people. It is just for presentation of the date field. I have [written about this to clear things up for new users of Talend](https://www.tobiasmaasland.de/2017/07/20/using-date-in-talend-etl-jobs/).

Comment: Hahaha, this kind of thing is a bit weird. People will expect that the date will be value-formatted

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to group or to sort the result on those columns?
It seems you want to sort.
In this case use tSortRow instead of tAggregateRow.
Else, share your input sample and the expected result.

Hope this helps.
TRF

Comment: Does this help or not. A feedback would be appreciate.

Comment: sorry, just read it by now. What I wanna do is grouping, it doesn't have to be sorted

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with an order issue.

To correctly use tAggregateRow, you need to make sure the data is already ordered afaik. The order in your case needs to be first operator, then pinjam.

This can be done with the database beforehand or with a tSortRow as TRF suggested.

The works of Talend are somewhat questionable sometimes...

Comment: but when I try grouping like counting fntranscid by operator, it works fine even without tsortrow

Comment: Could be that grouping with one column works fine. Have you tried the suggested approach? Otherwise we wouldn't know if the answer helped at all.